# G.C.D. of two elements in a U.F.D.

Tags: abstract-algebra, unique-factorization-domains

The following Theorems are already known:

1)If $R$ is a U.F.D., then g.c.d. of any two elements exists.
2)In a P.I.D., two ideals $(a)$ and $(b)$ are co-maximal iff g.c.d$(a,b)=1.$

**My Question:**

If $R$ is a U.F.D. and $a,b\in R\setminus${$0$}.
Define: $N:$$R\setminus${$0$}$\rightarrow \mathbb{N}\cup${$0$}.
Now, Suppose that g.c.d.$(N(a),N(b))>1.$

**My Question:**

I want to prove that g.c.d.$(a,b)\neq 1.$

**My Intuition:**

It holds because:
By Theorem 1 above, g.c.d.$(a,b)$ exists.
Suppose, g.c.d.$(a,b)= 1.$
$\implies (a),(b)$ are two co-maximal ideals of $R$. [ by Theorem 2 above]
$\implies$ for any $a\in (a)$ and $b \in (b)$
$(N(a),N(b))=1$ 
$\implies$ Contradiction to the assumption that g.c.d$(N(a),N(b))>1.$

Is my Intuition correct? Please provide me some Hints and Insights.

**Another Question:**
Can the above results be generalized for Integral domains that may not be U.F.D if g.c.d of two elements exists?

**Note:**
Here, $R$ contains $1\neq 0.$
U.F.D.=Unique Factorization Domain
P.I.D.=Principal Ideal Domain

Comment: $N$ is any old map from nonzero elements of $R$ to nonnegative integers?

Comment: Yes, But As per my thought, constant maps won't be useful ones for the above question. So, Please avoid those.

Comment: Please double check the statement of the exercise since it is likely you misread it (or missed some context that further defines $N$)

Comment: @BillDubuque it's my original question. I haven't taken it from some exercise. But the definition of $N$ is correct.

Comment: What motivated the question?  Experience with some specific maps $N$?

Comment: I think we have established that my answer answers your question, Kumar. You have the option of "accepting" it by clicking in the check-mark next to it.

Answer (score 1):

As OP confirms that any old nonconstant map $N$ will do, let $R$ be any UFD, let $a,b$ be any two nonzero elements of $R$ with $\gcd(a,b)=1$, define $N$ by $N(a)=6$, $N(b)=10$, and $N(c)$ is whatever you like for $c\ne a$, $c\ne b$. Then $\gcd(N(a),N(b))=\gcd(6,10)=2\ne1$, but $\gcd(a,b)=1$.

Comment: Please excuse my rudeness, @Kumar, but if an example that accords with the definition you have established is not a counterexample to your intuition, that means that your definition does not adequately represent your intuition.

Comment: What I have written, Kumar, doesn't depend on the countability or otherwise of $R$. It works as long as $R$ has more than two elements.